# Wield scope in reflux and immutable js ES6 webpack chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, refluxjs

I am experiencing wield scoping issue in ES6 with webpack and chrome

Here is my code:

```
'use strict'
import Reflux from 'reflux'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import Something from 'something'
import Cursor from 'immutable/contrib/cursor'

// everything is working in this scope

export default Reflux.createStore({
    init: function() {
        console.log(Something) // Something Not defined
        console.log(Cursor) //Cursor Not defined
        console.log(Reflux) // Reflux Not defined
    },
    ... some other code
})
```

so the question is, why things are defined in the scope above but not in the scope in the init function? thanks for the help

The code compiled after babel is like
    "use strict";

```
var _interopRequire = function (obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ?     obj["default"] : obj; };

var Reflux = _interopRequire(require("reflux"));

var Immutable = _interopRequire(require("immutable"));

var Something = _interopRequire(require("something"));

var Cursor = _interopRequire(require("immutable/contrib/cursor"));

// everything is working in this scope

module.exports = Reflux.createStore({
    init: function init() {
        console.log(Something); // Something Not defined
        console.log(Cursor); //Cursor Not defined
        console.log(Reflux);
    } });
```

Comment: What does the generated code look like?

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function `init: () => {...}`instead of `init: function init() {...}`?